# Issue after setting header and footer in jquery mobile android

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In ma project i have set header and footer to fixed position know the issue is when i click any where on the page the header moves a bit from its position can anyone tell me how to solve this issue i am using 
**jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js 
 jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/, use proper JQM's html markup.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i had already use this but still header is moving a bit when i click on the page ..